# Do I need to delete a vector?

Tags: c++, graph

I want to make a graph from input from a text file in the format:

```
vertex1 vertex2 cost time
```

where vertex1 and vertex2 are strings that form an edge and cost and time are the properties of that edge. This information will be used to construct the Graph based on cost. I want to plan out the project before coding it so I have a good idea of what to do. So far I decided on the following classes:

```
class Edge {
private:
  int vertex1;
  int vertex1;
  int cost;
  int time;

public:
  Edge(int v1, int v2, int cost, int time) {
    this->vertex1 = v1;
    this->vertex2 = v2;
    this->cost = cost;
    this->time = time;
  }

  ~Edge();

  int getEdgeCost();

  int getEdgeTime();
};


class Graph {
private:
  vector<Edges> edge; //edges in graph

public:
  Graph() : edge(0) {}

  ~Graph(){}

  int getTotalCost();

  int getTotalTime();

  void addEdge(Edge e);  

  Graph getMinSpanTree();   
};


class Vertex {
private:
  string name;
  int number;
  bool visited;
  vector<Edges> connEdges;  // vector of all edges connected to this vertex

public:
  Vertex(string name, int number) {
    this->name = name;
    this->number = number;
    visited = true;
  }

  ~Vertex();

  string getName();

  int getNum();

  bool wasVisited();

  Graph getShortestPath();
};



int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  std::string ifileName = std::string(argv[1]);

  ifstream ifile;
  if(ifile)
    ifile.open(ifileName);

  Edge edge;
  Graph* p_graph;
  Vertex v;

  string vert1, vert2;
  int cost, time; 

  int i = 1; // numbers each vertex

  while(ifile.good()) {
  // read in input, put it in vars above, skipped for brevity

  // make the vertices
  v1 = new Vertex(vert1, i);
  i++; // increments vertex number
  v2 = new Vertex(vert2, i);
  i++;

  // make the edge 
  edge = new Edge(v1.getNum(), v2.getNum(), cost, time);

  // add it to graph
  p_graph->addEdge(edge);

}
```

Is my design correct or is it lacking something? Can it be improved?

Comment: In `main()`, where are `v1` and `v2` declared?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Overall**

Resolve all standard library entities with `std::`. *Never* put `using namespace` declarations in a header file, where most of his belongs.

**Class Edge**

You use initializer lists in some places (`Graph`), not in others. Be consistent. I advise using them always *where they're needed*, and not at all where they're not.  Also, there is no need for a destructor in this class unless you're expecting polymorphism and need virtual-dtor for a vtable. Finally, make your getters `const`

```
class Edge {
private:
  int vertex1;
  int vertex2;
  int cost;
  int time;

public:
  Edge(int v1, int v2, int cost, int time) 
    : vertex1(v1), vertex2(v2), cost(cost), time(time)
  {
  }

  int getVertex1() const { return vertex1; }
  // etc...
};
```

**Class Graph**

There are outright compilation bugs in this class. There is no such entity as `Edges`, yet you have a vector of them. Further, properly named it should be `edges` are a vector of `Edge`. Also, the initializer list in this class is pointless, as is the destructor and, as-written, the constructor. Finally, you may (or may not) want to pass your incoming edge as a const-ref (lots of opinions on that, I know).

```
class Graph {
private:
  vector<Edge> edges; //edges in graph

public:
  int getTotalCost();
  int getTotalTime();
  void addEdge(const Edge& e);  

  Graph getMST();   // get Minimum Spanning Tree
};
```

**Class Vertex**

As previously mentioned, use initializer lists and full `std::` namespace resolution. Like `Graph`, this uses `Edges` as a typename, but no such type exists. Again, we use `const` qualifiers on all getters, here also returning the name by const-ref rather than value-copy. Finally, no chance of ever *setting* `visited` to true unless you provide a setter for it, nor accessing or modifying the `edges` vector without providing some means to do so.

```
class Vertex
{
private:
    std::string name;
    int number;
    bool visited;
    std::vector<Edge> connEdges;  // vector of all edges connected to this vertex

public:
    Vertex(const std::string& name, int number)
        : name(name), number(number), visited(false)
    {
    }

    // edge accessors
    void addEdge(const Edge& edge) { connEdges.push_back(edge); }
    const std::vector<Edge>& getEdges() const { return edges; }

    // properties
    const std::string& getName() const { return name; }
    int getNum() const { return number; }
    bool wasVisited() const { return visited; }
    void setVisited(bool val = true) { visited = val; }

    Graph getShortestPath();
};
```

**main()**

This function is simply *loaded* with errors. Among them:

- `edge`  is not a pointer type, so that assignment won't event compile.
- `p_edge` is derferenced though it is never initialized, so that will likely outright-fault due to undefined behavior
- `ifile` is never opened before use, so nothing will be read there.
- it leaks memory, but only because of an error previously mentioned above. Were that coded correctly this would be a non-issue.

Comment: when I posted this code on codereview I rewrote main() I opened the ifile, removed p_edge, so you shouldn't be seeing these errors. Do they still show up when you view the thread? Also are there any other variables/functions that I am missing?

Comment: On thing you're missing is you *never* "fix" the posted code on CodeReview questions. It literally makes nonsense of any answers that were posted to *review* it. Add an addendum instead, but try to keep the original post intact.

Comment: When I posted this post on Stackoverflow C++ site I had these errors, then when you told me to post this on Stackoverflow CodeReview. Only then did I remove them so not to duplicate errors, so I didn't change the code after posting it on CodeReview but was wondering if somehow those errors didn't get changed from my post on C++ since you are still referring to p_edge and ifile not being opened as you did then which I thought I fixed.

Comment: Thank you for reviewing my code. Could you explain to my why you are using a reference to set addEdge in Graph class and an instance of Edge in Vertex class?

Comment: @Napalidon I just realized I changed that to a proper reference long ago and never bothered answering your comment. It was a mistake. it should have been a reference (and is now). Sorry about that. Online editor coding ftl. =P